# VBA Excel copying and pasting a Template

Tags: vba, excel, templates

Background story: I'm doing a little project that is for my little association to help people to have a clear and understandable accounting system.
I'm a total novice in VBA and I have been looking for a simple solution in the forum without success:/

My Excel file has basically two mains sheets. 
Compta: where I input data
Model: a template

The result that I want, is a when I press the button on "Compta", it generates a new Sheet with the template pasted on it and with the name that I have decided.

```
Sub lala()
'part one creating new sheet with "P21" the name of the sheet
Dim projname As Range
Set projname = Range("P21")
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = projname

'part two copying and pasting the template on the new sheet
Sheets("Model").Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy
'this is the line where my problem is residing 
Worksheets(projname).Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

My problem is that when it's executing my first part is going well but part 2 doesn't copy at all on the  on the new sheet. It generates a new workbook with the template on it.

Are there any simple solution? I know there is one but i can't put my finger on it..

Comment: You want to copy the worksheet named "template" and make a new sheet with the data in it, and just name it the value in `Range("P21")` ? but in which sheet does `Range("P21")`  exist ? in "Compta" or "template" ?

Comment: anyway, see my answer and code below, and see if it works as you intended

Comment: Yes the value Range("P21") comes from Compta where i fill in all the the basic data to personalise the template. The code works wonderfully thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below, there's no need to use `Activate` , `Select` and `Selection` which slows down your code run-time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub lala()

Dim projname As Range
Dim TmpltSht As Worksheet
Dim NewSht  As Worksheet

Set TmpltSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("template")
Set projname = Sheets("Compta").Range("P21")

' copy the template sheet
TmpltSht.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
Set NewSht = ActiveSheet
NewSht.Name = projname.Value ' <-- set the name of the new copied sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes it works, I just had to modify two things and it works to perfection. The code is understandable and elegant. Thank you very much!:))

Comment: @JeanCule  you're welcome, now comes your part when you mark it as "answer", by clicking the gray check-mark next to my answer (it will turn green)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I was stuck in VBA I'd just bring up the macro toolbar and record a macro. That generates VBA code you can examine within the VBA code area inside Excel. Then just see what the code that the recorded macro generates does and maybe tweak it a little. It's possible you don't want to copy the whole sheet but instead define a selection within the sheet and copy that.

Comment: Hello yes I have been trying to do that. Problem is i wanna make it automatic because the code won't know what projects names I intend to make in the futur.  -> Worksheets(projname).Select. Is there a way to call a specific Worksheet by using a variable ? Thanks :))